# SQL - Replace value of column from another column value with condition

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

Ok to make it very clear, 
i have table look like this:

```
ID          post_title                      post_type
------------------------------------------------------
1           product A                       product
2           product A - Size S              product_variation
3           product A - Size M              product_variation
4           product A - Size L              product_variation
5           product B                       product
6           product A - Size S              product_variation
7           product A - Size M              product_variation
8           product A - Size L              product_variation
9           product C                       product
10          product A - Size S              product_variation
11          product A - Size M              product_variation
12          product A - Size L              product_variation
13          product D                       product
14          product A - Size S              product_variation
15          product A - Size M              product_variation
16          product A - Size L              product_variation
```

i want to be like this one :

```
ID          post_title                      post_type
------------------------------------------------------
1           product A                       product
2           product A - Size S              product_variation
3           product A - Size M              product_variation
4           product A - Size L              product_variation
5           product B                       product
6           product B - Size S              product_variation
7           product B - Size M              product_variation
8           product B - Size L              product_variation
9           product C                       product
10          product C - Size S              product_variation
11          product C - Size M              product_variation
12          product C - Size L              product_variation
13          product D                       product
14          product D - Size S              product_variation
15          product D - Size M              product_variation
16          product D - Size L              product_variation
```

how to change the value post_title of "product_variation" following the value of post_type "product" as the parent.

and if i have about 1000 product, how can i change it...?

Comment: 6,7,8 are  fix id ?

Comment: yes it's fixed id

Answer (score 0):

you can use replace function

```
update tableName set post_title=REPLACE(post_title,'A','B') where ID in(6,7,8)
```

Comment: please try it first in demo if work than try in original

Comment: thank you for the query, but i manage to do it on adminer, as i have about 7000 product. how i change them in bulk?

Comment: this why i have ask you id is fix ?

Comment: than you should tell your full problem

Comment: hmm.. sorry if i am confused you, but i don't know exactly how to tell the problem in easy way. i don;t know what you mean the id is fix or not.